# MongoDB data model and update strategy

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection, named Players

```
_id, name, stats[ { stName, stValue, stCountC } ]
```

I will be updating various stats for each Player every day, but will only update the Stat values when a new value is found (ie, `new.stCount > existing.stCountC`). My general idea is to limit the stats array to 2 objects for each unique `stName` -- one for the Current value and one for the Previous value. By example therefore, let's say I find a new stat with count of 6, my query and update process would start with -

```
db.players.findOne({ name: "JSmith",
                     stats: { $elemMatch: { stName: "Avg", stCountC: 5 } } })
```

If the above query returns a document, then I update as follows -

1) Get JSmith's `stValue` where `stName = "Avg"` and `stCountP = 4` -

```
db.players.findOne({ name: "JSmith", stats: { stName: "Avg", stCountP: 4 } },
                   { stats.$.stValue })
```

2) Insert this value to my `StatsHistory` collection, which holds all historical values for each player for a single stat type -

```
db.statshistory.update({ Name: "JSmith", StatName: "Avg" },
                       { $addToSet : { oldValues : { stValue: <val>, stCount: 4 } } })
```

3) Update my `Players` collection -

```
db.players.update({ Name: JSmith },
                  { $push: { stats: { stName: "Avg", stValue: "98", stCountC: 6 } }
                    $pull: { stats: { stName: "Avg", stCountP: 4 } } })

db.players.update({ name: "JSmith", stats.stName: "Avg", stats.stCountC: 5 },
                  { $rename: { "stats.stCountC": "stats.stCountP" } })
```

I will be presenting data grids of current stat values from the Players collection (ie one row per player, one column per stat name). I will also have views that show trends of stat values, and assume I would use MongoDB's Aggregation functions to return these from my StatsHistory collection.

**Question:** Does the above data model and find/update process seem logical?

I'm obviously new to MongoDB, so apologies for any syntax errors or if the above seems totally inappropriate to my needs. Any feedback is much appreciated!

**Resolved:**
Thanks to [idbentley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488927/idbentley) for the suggestion below. It helped me devise the following database update procedure using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). Note the data model changed slightly -- the `Players` collection now only holds the most current stat values, each attempted update pass updates a `LastScan` date stamp on the main record, and each stat update provides a date stamp `LastUpdate`. Stat count is still used to check if returned stat is newer. This procedure also ensures that any new players / stats are upserted to the collections.

```
async.series([
  function(cb){ db.statshistory.update({ Name: <name>, StatName: <statname> },
                                       { $set : { LastScan: new Date() }},
                                       { upsert: true },
                                       function() { cb(); });
  }
  ,function(cb){ db.statshistory.update({ Name: <name>, StatName: <statname>, OldValues: { $not : { $elemMatch : { StCount: <statcount> }}}},
                                        { $push : { OldValues: { LastUpdate: new Date(), StCount: <statcount>, StValue: <statvalue> }}},
                                        function() { cb(); });
  }
  ,function(cb){ db.players.update({ Name: <name> },
                                   { $set : { LastScan: new Date() }},
                                   { upsert: true },
                                   function() { cb(); });
  }
  ,function(cb){ db.players.update({ Name: <name> },
                                   { $pull : { Stats: { StName: <statname>, StCount: { $ne: <statcount> }}}},
                                   function() { cb(); });
  }
  ,function(cb){ db.players.update({ Name: <name>, Stats: { $not : { $elemMatch : { StName: <statname>, StCount: <statcount> }}}},
                                   { $push : { Stats: { LastUpdate: new Date(), StCount: <statcount>, StValue: <statvalue> }}},
                                   function() { cb(); });
  }]
  ,function() { console.log('update complete'); }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be making things more complicated than necessary.

My understanding of your requirements:

1. Each player has a number of statistics that change over time.
2. We should maintain a full history of a players stats over time, but most often we only need the current and previous stats

If I understand correctly, then I would change things slightly.

First, I would add a `current` flag to the embedded `stats` documents.

Then your workflow changes to:

```
db.statshistory.update( { Name: <name>, StatName: <statname> },
    { $addToSet : { oldValues : { <statobj> } } } );

db.player.update( { Name: <name>, stats:
    { $elemMatch: { stName: <statname>} } },
    { $pull: { current: false } } );

db.player.update( {Name: <name>, stats: 
    { $elemMatch: { stName: <statname>, current: true } } },
    { $set: { stats.current: false } } );

db.player.update({Name: <name>},
    { $addToSet: { <statobj>, current: true } });
```

Because this uses multiple updates, it won't work well in a multi-threaded environment.